# What actions can I take when a travel agent is very slow in rescheduling a cancelled flight?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, travel-agency

I was scheduled to fly from Barcelona to Manila on April 21st 2022 with a return on May 21st. The airline Lufthansa cancelled part of the flight on May 21st. I talked to the travel agent and they said there's an option to reschedule the return for May 20th and I asked them to do this. I made this request on March 16th and the travel agent still hasn't confirmed that the return flight has been moved.

Any time I contact them about it they just say that it's still processing they are waiting for Lufthansa to confirm the change - meanwhile if I go to the Lufthansa website and check myself I can see they have several available flights departing from Manila to Barcelona on May 20th, so I don't see why it should be taking so long to process this change.

The outgoing flight is in two weeks and I still don't know if we have a return flight home or not. Every time I contact the travel agent they give me the same answers and apologies about the delay but there seems to be no progress at all.

Do I have any legal actions that I can take to escalate a situation like this? I am worried that this will still be stuck  'processing' on April 21st and we'll be forced to make the choice of going and hoping that the return flight will be resolved by the time we are due to return or cancelling altogether and claiming the refund. Do travel agents/airlines have any legal obligation to provide a *timely* rebooking in the case of cancelled flights?

Comment: Do you have access to your booking via LH’s website or via checkmytrip? If so, what does it say (date and status)?

Comment: This is one of the strange things also. When I check the booking on LH website it says that the Singapore-Frankfurt and Frankfurt-Barcelona legs are *already* moved to May 20th but the Manila-Singapore (which is carried by Singapore Airlines) still shows May 21st. Obviously this is no good as the departure point of origin flight comes the day after the transfers. I've raised this with the travel agent and they just say they are still processing it with Lufthansa to rebook the flights.

Comment: Is the travel agent a person you have met personally or an online company?

Comment: It's an online company.

Comment: I realise it's no help to you now but there's almost no reason ever to use a travel agent of any type for booking flights.

Comment: If the flight has been cancelled is there any reason why you can't just go via EU261?